# Set table vs multi set table performance

Tags: teradata

I have to prepare a table where I will keep weekly results for some aggregated data. Table will have 30 fields (10 CHARACTERs, 20 DECIMALs), I think I will have 250k rows weekly.

In my head I can see two scenarios:

1. Set table and relying on teradata in preventing duplicate rows - it should skip duplicate entries while inserting new data
2. Multi set table with UPI - it will give an error upon inserting duplicate row.

INSERT statement is going to be executed through VBA on excel, where handling possible teradata errors is not a problem.

Which scenario will be faster to run in a year time where there will be circa 14 millions rows

Is there any other way to have it done?

Regards

Comment: do you only wish to maintain unique records in your tables across a specific key column @kwasny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a high level, since you would be having a comparatively high data count on your table, it is advisable not to use SET tables, rather go with the multiset table. 
For more info you can refer to this link

```
http://www.dwhpro.com/teradata-multiset-tables/
```

Comment: thank you very much for this link - information posted there explained very well advantages and disadvantages for both approach

Answer (score 0):

Why do you care about Duplicate Rows? When you store weekly aggregates there should be no duplicates at all. And Duplicate Rows are not the same as duplicate Primary Key values.

Simply choose a PI which fits best your join/access pattern (maybe partition by date). To avoid any potential duplicates you might simply use MERGE instead of INSERT.

Comment: I should not have duplicate rows while loading data - I was trying to find out solution if someone will try to load data again. That pushes me to rely on loading application not to load the same data twice, which is fine. I should not allow to have duplicated rows but I should allow to have duplicate primary key values, if there is a need for 'counter' or 'corrective' transaction - thank you very much for pointing this to me.